# Parse strings, and add a number to the value

Tags: string, vba, excel, delimiter

I have an Excel table in which sometimes an entire cell has the following content:

```
pos=51;70;112;111;132;153
```

Note the whole content in in a single cell, that is to say the value `51;70;112...` are strings clumped together in a single cell and not in their own cells.

Can I write a macro that in all cells that contain the keyphrase `"pos="`, add 2 to each value, so that the end result is:

```
pos=53;72;114;113;134;155
```

Comment: Has it always 5 semicolons or does that differ as well?

Comment: @rene: actually, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code that will do it (tested on a sample on my Excel 2003):

```
Sub t()
Dim rCells As Range, c As Range
Dim arr As Variant, i As Integer

'Define the range to apply the code
Set rCells = Range("A1")
For Each c In rCells
    'check if the cell desserves to be changed (could be adapted though to another check)
    If Left(c.Value, 4) = "pos=" Then
        'split all the values after the "pos=" into an array
        arr = Split(Mid(c.Value, 5, Len(c.Value)), ";")
        'add +2 to every value of the array (we convert the value to be sure, probably unneeded)
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
            arr(i) = CLng(arr(i)) + 2
        Next i
        'set back the value to the worksheet
        c.Value = "pos=" & Join(arr, ";")
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Note that I didn't add the error checking part if your values aren't well formated.

Answer (score 3):

You know that you can easily split data without using macros, right? Just use the TextToColumns function on the Data tab

But if you really want a macro, you can do something like the following:

```
Sub AddNumber()
    Dim numberToAdd As Integer
    numberToAdd = 2

    Set myRange = Range("A1:A5")
    For Each myCell In myRange
    If Left(myCell.Value, 4) = "pos=" Then
        arEquality = Split(myCell, "=")
        arElements = Split(arEquality(1), ";")
        For i = 0 To UBound(arElements)
            arElements(i) = arElements(i) + numberToAdd
        Next
        myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = arEquality(0) + "=" + Join(arElements, ";")
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Needs a check for the `pos=` string

Comment: I know and I was going to refine it, but I saw JMax's answer coming in with basically the same solution, so it seemed a bit stupid to continue. But since you were so kind to comment, I'll update the code anyway :-)

Comment: @JMax: as you say, no error checking, so it can still blow up big time; let's hope this is not going to be used for precision bombing